# Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I kind have been stuck with this error, when i'm using localhost my website sends its mails smoothly, but when I uploaded it to the live server, I got this error.

```
PHP
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2055
```

And here is the error message from print_debugger()

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 101 Network is unreachable
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

**Here is my codes for email.php**

```
<?php

$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['charset']   = "utf-8";
$config['newline']   = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype']  = "html";

$config['smtp_user'] = "**********@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "**********";
```

Comment: Maybe your server is blacklisted as a spammer? I have the exact same config, and it works fine.